# mandatory field in VB and save Button

Tags: vb.net

if somebody can help me in VB coding to show required field to be mandatory when I click save Button and the function of saving should not be work till all required field to be filled 
(please visual basic codes not other )

Comment: Clue - Set the button to disabled in the form designer and use the `.TextChanged` event to check that the TextBox has been filled in properly. If so, enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple If function that occurs when the button is pressed.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then 

    Msgbox("A field is missing")
    Exit Sub 'To avoid saving, escape the procedure

    Else 
     ' code to save goes here
    End If

    End Sub
```

Here, I assume that TextBox1 and TextBox2 are the fields you want and Button1 is the save button.

Comment: The comment above by @David Wilson is a very elegant way of doing it. Thank you. I learnt something too. Anyways, If my answer helped you ASHRAF, kindly mark this as an answer in order that others may find this solution in the future. Thank you. And you are welcome.